# How to add records to a pivot table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a user, student and subject model and I want to register a student into many subjects. So I created a StudentRegistration controller and in my create view I show all the subjects that belong to the course of the current logged in user.

StudentRegistration.php create function

```
public function create()
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $student_id = Student::where('user_id', $user_id)->first();
    $course = $student_id->course->id;
    $subjects = Subject::where('course_id', $course)->get();

    return view('student.create', compact('subjects'));

}
```

In the create template I show all the subjects as checkbox because a user can register for multiple subjects.

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'action'=>'StudentRegistration@store', 'files'=>true]) !!}
    @foreach($subjects as $subject)
    <div class="label-box">
        {!! Form::label('name', $subject->name) !!}
        {!! Form::checkbox('subject_id[]', $subject->id, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    @endforeach
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Create User', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    </div>      
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I have this in my Student.php for the many to many relationship:

```
public function subjects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subject');
}
```

I created a pivot table named Student_Subject. So, during the store, how can I save all the selected subjects into pivot table (`student_subject`).

I tried using this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->except('_token');
    $subject_count = count($data['subject_id']);
    for($i=0; $i < $subject_count; $i++){
       $student = Student::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
       $student->subjects()->attach($data['subject_id'][$i]);
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
"Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::subjects does not exist."
```

And how can I view all the course subjects which the student is not registered at?

I have this:

```
Route::get('/studentsubjects', function(){
    $student_id = Student::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
    $course = $student_id->course->id;
    $subjects = $student_id->subjects;

    echo 'Registered at' .'<br>';
    foreach ($subjects as $registered) {
        echo $registered->name .'<br>';
    }

    $unregistered = Subject::where('course_id', $course)->except($subjects);
});
```

And see this error:

```
"Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::except does not exist."
```

Comment: You forgot to 'get' the Students query. `$student = Student::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();` as long as you don't perform a fetch function (get, first etc,) it will still be a builder and not an instance of Student or Collection of students.

Comment: It was indeed the first() missing.

Comment: Something I would like to amend in my registration view is to show only subjects that the student is not registered at. Hope you dont mind supporting on that on a side note.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$student = Student::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
```

is not enough to get the Student model, you're only getting the query object here.

In order to actually get the student, use the following:

```
$student = Student::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
```

Even better if `user_id` is the primary key for your model `Student`:

```
$student = Student::find(Auth::user()->id);
```

As a side note, you can access directly the user ID from the `Auth` interface using `Auth::id()` instead of `Auth::user()->id`, resulting in:

```
$student = Student::find(Auth::id());
```

Comment: Appreciate the support the support and the user id tip. It does what I want now.

Comment: Something I would like to amend in my registration view is to show only subjects that the student is not registered at. Hope you dont mind supporting on that on a side note.

Comment: @WosleyAlarico You may want to open a new question as this is an entirely different problem, and, at first glance, a bit trickier than just a one liner solution. A non-ideal solution would be to get all the subjects, get all the student's subjects and then remove the ones in common from the subjects array.